# Android: replace widgets in different activities

Tags: android, view, android-activity, replace

The thing I want to do, is actually an "Action Bar", like this:
[image: tapatalk]

And when starting an activity, I want to replace the views beneath the action bar.
Example of main.xml (simplified):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <!-- SIMPLIFIED ACTION BAR -->
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="#333333">

        <Button android:id="@+id/actionBtn"
            android:text="@string/actionText"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="0.0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/fillImage"
            android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_menu_agenda"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_unselect"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/btn_default_holo_light"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/BUTTON1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="@string/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/klassenBtn"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In my MainActivity.java, I do
     setContentView(R.layout.main,xml)

Inside web.xml:

```
    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/webView1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Now I want to replace BUTTON1 (@+id/BUTTON1) with webView1 (@+id/webView1) in a different activity (WebActivity.java)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to make Button1  invisible (Gone), and show webview1 there ?

Comment: haven't thought of that.. that would make it possible to do all in one xml, right? what about  the space allocated to the widgets then?

Comment: "GONE" wont allocate space between widgets. Because widget gone if you set it with it.

Comment: Did that in eclipse, and it worked. Now I still need to load an URL in the WebView that's displayed... How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put webview and button in same layout. If you set its visibility it wont allocate space between widgets.

Thenonly you can change the visibility of your widget.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:background="#333333"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/actionBtn"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_unselect"
        android:contentDescription="@string/fillImage"
        android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_menu_agenda"
        android:text="@string/actionText"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/BUTTON1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/klassenBtn"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_default_holo_light"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/button"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<WebView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="gone" 
    android:background="#ad00fc"/>
```

Comment: Before I accept it: how do load an URL in webView1 from within a different activity? I already tried "  LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
  View mainLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
  View webview = (View) mainLayout.findViewById(R.id.webView);" but it didn't work...

Comment: Lol, you do this for reputation :p anyway, I will post.

Comment: Ask your other question by putting your xml and code to let other programmer understand you easly